# How to pass command line arguments to cmake in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I cloned a github repo. It has been set to built with cmake. I now want to build it in vscode, but I cannot find a place to set cmake command line argument.

When I execute cmake configure in vscode, it complains cannot find some headers or libs. I test in terminal, when I set -D arguments, this error can be solved.

So, I wonder is there a place to pass cmake command line arguments in vscode?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Does anyone know how to pass args to the "Run" button in the status bar at the bottom? I don't see any settings to be able to modify this. For example if I want to run my binary like this `./binary -c config`

Answer (score 24):

Passing information onto CMake in VSCode happens in the `settings.json` file.

You need to install the [CMake Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) extention first.

Then, open the command pallet in VSCode with `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type `Open Settings`.

Once selected, VSCode will show a `settings.json` file where you should add  `cmake.configureArgs` e.g.:

```json
{
 "other":"settings",
 "cmake.configureArgs": [
        "-DOPTIONA=ON",
        "-DOPTIONB=ON"
    ],
}
```

The `cmake.configureArgs` array of arguments is the same as you would normally use during a command-line cmake configure e.g.

```sh
cmake -DOPTIONA=ON -DOPTIONB=ON ..
```

Comment: I needed "-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=path/to/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake" to integrate vcpkg. Thaks

Comment: Side note: this saves CMake command line arguments globally. If you need per-project configuration, save these settings to `${project_dir}/.vscode/settings.json`

Answer (score 0):

In general, command line arguments can be given by specifying `cmake.configureArgs` in the settings.json file, as shown by Jan Gabriel's answer.

But there is another setting (also in settings.json) specifically for -D arguments:

```json
{
    "cmake.configureSettings": {
        "OPTIONA": "ON",
        "OPTIONB": "ON"
    }
}
```

See https://vector-of-bool.github.io/docs/vscode-cmake-tools/settings.html